# If we are casting when using (int)(Math.random()), wouldn't our variable be assigned zero even if we multiplied by another value?

Tags: java, random, casting

I'm running through some mini-programming projects in a textbook and I was wondering, if we're casting to an int type in the following program, wouldn't `oneLength`, `twoLength`, `threeLength` all be assigned a value of 0? I know that since we are casting to an int, the values will be from 0 to 1, and this means that 0 will be inclusive, and 1 exclusive. If we have 0 * (12), 12 being the length of `wordListOne` as an example, wouldn't the final value be 0?

Here is the program:

public class ScribblePad {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] wordListOne = {"24/7", "multi-Tier", "30,000 foot", "B-to-B", "win-win", "front-end", "web-based", "pervasive", "smart", "six-sigma", "critical-patch", "dynamic"};

    String[] wordListTwo = {"empowered", "sticky", "value-added", "oriented", "centric", "distributed", "clustered", "branded", "outside-the-box", "positioned", "networked", "focused", "leveraged", "aligned", "targeted", "shared", "cooperative", "accelerated"};

    String[] wordListThree = {"process", "tipping-point", "solution", "architecture", "core competency", "strategy", "mindshare", "portal", "space", "vision", "paradigm", "mission"};


    // oneLength : number of items in array

    int oneLength = wordListOne.length;
    int twoLength = wordListTwo.length;
    int threeLength = wordListThree.length;

    // rand1 : casting to int value

    int rand1 = (int) (Math.random() * oneLength);
    int rand2 = (int) (Math.random() * twoLength);
    int rand3 = (int) (Math.random() * threeLength);


    // phrase : 

    String phrase = wordListOne[rand1] + " " + wordListTwo[rand2] + " " + wordListThree[rand3];

    System.out.println("What we need is a " + phrase); }}
```

Really appreciate the help I get, and thank you so much.

Comment: Can you explain what the function of parentheses `()` in an expression is?

Comment: Do you mean (int) in this case? We are using a casting process to change the type from double to int.

Comment: I didn't mean those parentheses; I meant the ones in `(Math.random() * oneLength)`.

Comment: We are generating a random double value (from 0 to 1), then we are multiplying it by the length of wordListOne, which in this case is 12. The double value is casted into an int value.

Comment: Okay, then why do you expect the value of the right-hand side (the expression that is assigned into `rand1`) to be zero?

Comment: I was thinking that, since double will go from 0.0 to 1.0, when we cast to an int, we will get 0 regardless. So whether we multiply it by the length of oneLength or twoLength or threeLength, we will still get 0. I'm a little confused as to how we wouldn't.

Comment: Can you explain better this: "*if we're casting to an int type in the following program, wouldn't oneLength, twoLength, threeLength all be assigned a value of 0?*" ?

Comment: Sure, so, if we know that the random number generated will be a double ranging from 0.0 to 1.0, if we cast this to an int, then the random number generated would be zero overall since 0 is inclusive and 1 is exclusive [0,1). If we multiply 0 by either 12, representing the length of wordListOne as an example, we would get (0*12), which is zero, right?

Comment: `Math.random()` is a double that goes from 0.0 to 1.0. _You then multiply it by 12_, so it goes from 0.0 to 12.0.

Comment: I think you need to read the concept of "order of operations" and what the purpose of `()` in `(Math.random() * oneLength)` is. Try the difference between `(int) (Math.random() * oneLength)` and `((int) Math.random()) * oneLength`. Note that the parentheses affect _the type of the expression_ (double or int), not just the numeric value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int rand1 = (int) (Math.random() * oneLength);
```

We know that `oneLength == 12`.

Image if `Math.random()` gives you `0.72` - now multiply it for `12` - the result is `9.12` - now cast it to an Integer - the result is `9`.

You will get a value of `0` in case `Math.random()` gives you a number **less** then `0,0833..`, why?

Because: `12 * x < 1 => x < 1/12 = 0.0833..`

Comment: I see the mistake I was making. I was casting the random number generated before multiplying and getting the result. What I was doing, in this case, was casting 0.72 before multiplying it. So, basically, I was multiplying 0 by 12 and getting 0 as the result.

Comment: @Sampoo Parentheses matter.

Comment: You shouldn't have that problem, the brackets you put are right! I also tried...